# Ubuntu 22.04, 21,10, 20,.04 freeze on Laptop HP 15-eh1xxx

Tags: hp, freeze, 22.04, amd-ryzen

Laptop HP 15-eh1600ng, AMD Ryzen 7 5700u freezes/crashes with black screen, only turnoff with button works. This happens more or less randomly with several apps. But it can be reproduced using the app digikam -> image processing -> enhancement -> sharpen. When executing or trying the sharpening function laptop freezes immediately.

Tried with several OS (Ubuntu 20.04, Ubuntu 21.10, Ubuntu 22.04, OpenSuse Tumbleweed), updating amdgpu drivers on Ubuntu 20.04 no result.

No log entries with relation to this error, only turnoff with button.

Does anyone know why's this happening and how to solve it.
Thank you

Comment: Is the system going down via kernel panic?  (ie. does it respond to SysRq or direct command from keyboard to linux kernel?) and what kernel stack did you try with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS?  (GA?, HWE? OEM? did you try another stack?)

Comment: Not responding to SysRq command. Kernel stack of 20.04.3 LTS is HWE, I guess.

Answer (score 2):

I've been experiencing the same issue with similar hardware, HP 15-eh1075cl.
Ubuntu 22.04 5.15.0-41.44-generic.
It's so weird because nothing interesting shows up in dmesg.

I've noticed the crash happens when using firefox.  Usually within a few minutes of use (like a youtube video).  I've also notice it crash during synaptic or mpv use.

Not using firefox, or synaptic or mpv, and instead using google chrome: I have not experienced the crash so far.

I also added the kernel flags specified here https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Ryzen
under "Soft lock freezing", but was still experiencing the issue when using firefox.

Comment: Seems like a hardware issue.  Even a year later, with latest amd proprietary radeon drivers, I still get the random crashes when video is played.  Ultimately, I replaced the laptop with an intel-based one.